# How to exclude few columns and replace negative values in Big data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1]})
```

In my real data, I have more than 100 columns. What I would like to do is excluding two columns, I would like replace the negative values in all other columns to zero

I tried this but it works for all columns.

```
df[df < 0] = 0
```

Is the only way is to have all column names in a list and run through a loop like as shown below

```
col_list = ['a1','a2','a3','a4',..........'a100']   # in this `a21`,a22` columns are ignored from the list

for col in col_list:
    df[col] = [df[col]<0] = 0
```

As you can see it's lengthy and inefficient.

Can you help me with any efficient approach to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem `df[col_list]` return boolean `DataFrame`, so cannot be filtered by `df[df < 0] = 0` with specified columns names, is necessary use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
col_list = df.columns.difference(['a21','a22'])
m = df[col_list] < 0

df[col_list] = df[col_list].mask(m, 0)
```

EDIT:

For numeric columns without `a21` and `a22` use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a21':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[-7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,-7,1,'a'], <- object column because last `a`
         'E':[5,3,-6,9,2,-4],
         'a22':list('aaabbb')
})


col_list = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns.difference(['a21','a22'])
m = df[col_list] < 0
df[col_list] = df[col_list].mask(m, 0)
print (df)
  a21  B  C   D  E a22
0   a  4  0   1  5   a
1   b  5  8   3  3   a
2   c  4  9   5  0   a
3   d  5  4  -7  9   b
4   e  5  2   1  2   b
5   f  4  3   a  0   b
```

Comment: So, I have to prepare a list. Is there an option to exclude those two columns and do it without `col_list`?

Comment: I get an error like this `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @SSMK - First or second solution?

Comment: Is it due to datatype? my dataframe also has `str` ,`int`,`float` columns

Comment: I get the same error still. Will try changing the data type now

Comment: @SSMK - hmmm, then it means there are some non numeric columns in data

Comment: @SSMK - You can check it be `col_list.difference(df[col_list].select_dtypes(np.number).columns)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205079/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037211/derive-date-column-based-on-different-types-of-values

Comment: @TheGreat - There was no similar question some time ago?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Are you able to access the question now?

Comment: @TheGreat - No, I only remember some time ago I slove similar problem, not for you?

Comment: No, this ques is open for more than 3-4 hour

Answer (score 2):

How about simple clipping at 0?

```
df[col_list] = df[col_list].clip(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. But is ere any way to do this without `col_list`?

Comment: @SSMK you're gonna have to specify which columns you want somehow. Is `col_list = [i for i in df.columns if i not in ['a21', 'a22']]` acceptable?