# Derive date column based on different types of values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id' :[1,2,3,4,5],
                        'date_of_interview':['2007-05-27','2008-03-13','2010-11-19','2011-10-05','2004-11-02'],
                        'Age':[31,35,78,72,43],
                        'value':[6,0.33,1990,np.nan,2001],
                        'age_detected':[25,35,98,65,40]})
df['date_of_interview'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_interview'])
```

I would like to create a new column called `dis_date` based on `value` and `age_detected` column

Ex: subject_id = 1 has date_of_interview as 2007-05-27. If we look at his value column, we can see that he has a value of 6 which means we have to subtract 6 years from the date_of_interview to get `2001-05-27` as dis_date

Whereas if you look at subject_id = 3, he has a year value in value column, so his dis_date will be `1990-11-19`

When there is `NA` in value column, we have to look at his `age_detected` column and subtract it from `Age` to get the number of years.

Ex: subject_id = 4 has `Age` as 72 and `AGE_DETECTED` as 65. now the diff is 7 and his dis_date will be `2004-10-05`

Please note values in value column if less than 6 digits represent no of years. If it's 1, it means subtract 1 year. If it's 0.33 meaning subtract 4 months. 1 year = 12 months. 0.33 = 3.96 months (4 months)

I was trying something like this but it doesn't help

```
for i in range(len(df['value'])):

    if (len(str(df['value'][i]))) < 6:
        df['dis_date'] = df['date_of_interview'] - pd.DateOffset(years=df['value'][i])
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: How would you define `0.33` year? `12/4`?

Comment: 1 year = 12 months. 0.33 = 3.96 moths (4 months)

Comment: I will have a look into this when I get home this evening.

Comment: Is `2007-12-13` correct? Because if subtract 4 months get `2007-11-13`

Comment: Might be my sample is incorrect. Will check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution are created helper columns for verify replaced years or subtracted months:

```
#if value less like 1 multiple by 12, another values set to NaNs
df['m1'] = np.where(df['value'].lt(1), df['value'].mul(12).round(), np.nan)
#if values more like 1000 it is year
df['y1'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].gt(1000))

#if values between 1, 1000 is necessary subtract years from value column
y1 = df['Age'].sub(df['age_detected'])
df['y2'] = np.where(y1.between(1, 1000), df['date_of_interview'].dt.year.sub(y1), np.nan)
#joined years to one column
df['y'] = df['y1'].fillna(df['y2'])

#replaced years by another column
f1 = lambda x: x['date_of_interview'] - pd.DateOffset(year=(int(x['y'])))
df['dis_date1'] = df.dropna(subset=['date_of_interview','y']).apply(f1, axis=1)
#subtracted months if non missing values
f1 = lambda x: x['date_of_interview'] - pd.DateOffset(months=(int(x['m1'])))
df['dis_date2'] = df.dropna(subset=['m1']).apply(f1, axis=1)

#join together
df['dis_date'] = df['dis_date1'].fillna(df['dis_date2'])
print (df)
   subject_id date_of_interview  Age    value  age_detected   m1      y1  \
0           1        2007-05-27   31     6.00            25  NaN     NaN   
1           2        2008-03-13   35     0.33            35  4.0     NaN   
2           3        2010-11-19   78  1990.00            98  NaN  1990.0   
3           4        2011-10-05   72      NaN            65  NaN     NaN   
4           5        2004-11-02   43  2001.00            40  NaN  2001.0   

       y2       y  dis_date1  dis_date2   dis_date  
0  2001.0  2001.0 2001-05-27        NaT 2001-05-27  
1     NaN     NaN        NaT 2007-11-13 2007-11-13  
2     NaN  1990.0 1990-11-19        NaT 1990-11-19  
3  2004.0  2004.0 2004-10-05        NaT 2004-10-05  
4  2001.0  2001.0 2001-11-02        NaT 2001-11-02
```